# Do we really need to explicitly add Sencha View to Viewport?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In all the examples on Sencha Touch 2 I see code samples like:-

```
//contents of app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    views: ['MyView'],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView');
    }
});
```

However, the code generated by Sencha Cmd is like:-

```
//contents of app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    views: ['MyView'],

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyView')); // <--- NOTICE THIS LINE
    }
});
```

Notice that the example code did not add the newly instantiated View to `Viewport` but the actual code did. Are both codes equivalent? In the example code, how will the View add itself to the `Viewport` or that is optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.Viewport is basically a container with the layout set as 'card'.

In your first sample, the class should have the config option 'fullscreen' set to true.
Setting fullscreen:true will automatically add the comoponent to the viewport when an instance is created.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.test', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',            
    config: {
        fullscreen:true,
        html: ['screen2'].join("")
    }
});    

Ext.create('MyApp.view.test');
```

From the doc for fullscreen

> Force the component to take up 100% width and height available, by
>   adding it to Ext.Viewport.

In the second sample, a component is added to the viewport. (Don't need the fullscreen option). Like adding a panel into a container.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.home', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'homecontainer',            
    config: {
        html: ['test'].join("")
    }
});
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.home'));
```

From the doc for viewport

> Because Ext.Viewport extends from Ext.Container, it has as layout
>   (which defaults to Ext.layout.Card). This means you can add items to
>   it at any time, from anywhere in your code. The Ext.Viewport
>   fullscreen configuration is true by default, so it will take up your
>   whole screen.